# Why is my DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea()'d window not drawing the DWM borders?

Tags: c++, winapi, dwm

I've been following [MSDN's guide to using the DWM API to extend the frame into the client area](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb688195(v=vs.85).aspx), but redone so I can experiment with it once I have something working.

However, when I build it, using `cl wincompositiontest.cpp` in the Visual Studio 2013 x64 Native Tools Command Line, the program does not draw the window borders. The standard window buttons do work: I can see the Windows 7 button glow and tooltips, and clicking on the buttons does their respective action (so I can close this window). But nothing else works: I can't move or resize the window with the edges, and the borders don't draw, instead drawing white:

[image: Window]

`DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea()` returns `S_OK`.

What's going on? This is on Windows 7 x64 running in VirtualBox; I gave the code to a friend also running Windows 7 on real hardware and they get the same results. Thanks.

```
// 12 december 2016
#define UNICODE
#define _UNICODE
#define STRICT
#define STRICT_TYPED_ITEMIDS
// get Windows version right; right now Windows Vista
// unless otherwise stated, all values from Microsoft's sdkddkver.h
// TODO is all of this necessary? how is NTDDI_VERSION used?
// TODO plaform update sp2
#define WINVER          0x0600  /* from Microsoft's winnls.h */
#define _WIN32_WINNT        0x0600
#define _WIN32_WINDOWS  0x0600  /* from Microsoft's pdh.h */
#define _WIN32_IE           0x0700
#define NTDDI_VERSION       0x06000000
#include <windows.h>
#include <commctrl.h>
#include <uxtheme.h>
#include <windowsx.h>
#include <shobjidl.h>
#include <d2d1.h>
#include <d2d1helper.h>
#include <dwrite.h>
#include <usp10.h>
#include <msctf.h>
#include <textstor.h>
#include <olectl.h>
#include <shlwapi.h>
#include <dwmapi.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <string>

#pragma comment(linker, \
    "\"/manifestdependency:type='Win32' " \
    "name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' " \
    "version='6.0.0.0' " \
    "processorArchitecture='*' " \
    "publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' " \
    "language='*'\"")
#pragma comment(lib, "user32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "kernel32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "gdi32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "comctl32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "uxtheme.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "dwmapi.lib")

#define HR(call) printf("%s -> 0x%I32X\n", #call, call)

LRESULT CALLBACK wndproc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    RECT r;
    MARGINS margins;
    BOOL dwmHandled;
    LRESULT lResult;

    dwmHandled = DwmDefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam, &lResult);
    switch (uMsg) {
    case WM_CREATE:
        GetWindowRect(hwnd, &r);
        SetWindowPos(hwnd, NULL,
            r.left, r.top,
            r.right - r.left, r.bottom - r.top,
            SWP_FRAMECHANGED);
        // TODO if we pass SWP_NOOWNERZORDER || SWP_NOZORDER, the default frame is not correctly inhibited
        break;
    case WM_ACTIVATE:
        margins.cxLeftWidth = 8;
        margins.cxRightWidth = 8;
        margins.cyBottomHeight = 20;
        margins.cyTopHeight = 27;
        HR(DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(hwnd, &margins));
        break;
    case WM_NCCALCSIZE:
        if (wParam != (WPARAM) FALSE)
            return 0;
        break;
    case WM_CLOSE:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    }
    if (dwmHandled)
        return lResult;
    return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

int main(void)
{
    WNDCLASSW wc;
    HWND mainwin;
    MSG msg;

    ZeroMemory(&wc, sizeof (WNDCLASSW));
    wc.lpszClassName = L"mainwin";
    wc.lpfnWndProc = wndproc;
    wc.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    wc.hIcon = LoadIconW(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursorW(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) (COLOR_BTNFACE + 1);
    RegisterClassW(&wc);

    mainwin = CreateWindowExW(0,
        L"mainwin", L"Main Window",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        400, 400,
        NULL, NULL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);

    ShowWindow(mainwin, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
    UpdateWindow(mainwin);

    while (GetMessageW(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessageW(&msg);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For *WM_NCCALCSIZE* MSDN: *When wParam is TRUE, simply returning 0 without processing the NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS rectangles will cause the client area to resize to the size of the window, including the window frame. This will **remove** the window frame and caption items from your window, **leaving only the client area displayed**.*

Comment: @γηράσκωδ'αείπολλάδιδασκόμε yes, but take a look at the MSDN page I linked: it simply sets `pncsp->rgrc[0]` to itself without changing it, then instructs `WndProc()` to return 0 without calling `DefWIndowProc()`. Unless there's something subtle I'm missing (setting `pncsp->rgrc[0]` to itself is not the same as doing nothing?)?

Comment: Change the color of the *hbrBackground* to black

Comment: @γηράσκωδ'αείπολλάδιδασκόμε okay, that fixed everything except the border dragging, and now I'm not sure why. Would you know? (For hit testing, it appears `DwmDefWindowProc()` is not doing the hit testing for some reason, but the page I linked tells me how to do it in this case, which is not a problem.)

Comment: If you are not going to draw on the caption bar then you don't need all the extra code. Just call *DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea* and everything is fine

Comment: @γηράσκωδ'αείπολλάδιδασκόμε I'm not drawing yet, but I will be now that I have this much working. Is there a difference?

Comment: If you are going to draw on the extended frame then probably you need the code in the url you provided. Not sure though.

Comment: Right. I meant why is it that your suggestion of using the black brush for the background fixed my window drawing? Do you know that, or does it have to do with not drawing?

Comment: I used the black brush some years ago when i wanted to draw tranparently with directx. The idea is the same. Extend the frame to the whole form set the brush to black. I believe setting the brush to black is also setting the alpha value of the extended area to 0 and thus you can see the transparent borders

Comment: All right, that makes sense combined with some of the information on that page. Now I can continue experimenting with DWM frames. Thanks again!

Comment: Now the only thing I wonder is why the MSDN example works with `COLOR_WINDOW`; maybe it's a change from Vista to 7?...

Comment: You mean that the example worked in vista with COLOR_WINDOW and not on 7?

Comment: No, that the sample works on Microsoft's systems since they have images to show it, but on my system I get the output I showed above, except all white. The page explains the whole alpha stuff you were mentioning, but only for the thin edge around the client area and not for the whole window, so I wonder if something changed between Vista and 7.

Comment: For compatibility with Windows 10 you should not change the left/right/bottom borders. You can change the title-bar area and let the system handle the other borders. Or use custom borders but don't add system buttons.

Comment: Yes indeed. Have you tried to copy the entire code **exactly** as it is in the example to see if it works? Maybe you missed something. Eg the example calls *WM_PAINT* twice with some custom drawing.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani huh? will passing 0 in one of the MARGINS fields do that? I've just been using `AdjustWindowRectEx()` to get the system margins, and I haven't tested on Windows 8 or 10 yet...

Comment: @γηράσκωδ'αείπολλάδιδασκόμε admittedly not, but I can do that later...

Answer (score 4):

For compatibility with Windows 10, the left/right/bottom margins should be zero.

Usually you need to change the title bar area only. Therefore, only change the value for `margins.cyTopHeight`

Calculate the default border widths for the given window style using `AdjustWindowRectEx` and pass these values to `WM_NCCALCSIZE`, this will show the default borders.

`DwmDefWindowProc` is required in response to `WM_NCHITTEST` and `WM_NCMOUSELEAVE` only (but maybe the way you have set it up is better for future compatibility)

You also have to handle `WM_PAINT` for system buttons to display correctly. It's probably easier to hide the system buttons and draw your own buttons, so the title-bar is completely custom with its own background color.

Below is example for Windows 10, it should work for Windows 7. Application should be DPI aware otherwise there will be small display problems with borders.

```
void paint_caption(HWND hWnd, HDC hdc, int caption_height)
{
    RECT rc;
    GetClientRect(hWnd, &rc);
    rc.bottom = caption_height;

    HDC memdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    BITMAPINFOHEADER bmpInfoHdr = 
        { sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), rc.right, -rc.bottom, 1, 32 };
    HBITMAP hbitmap = 
        CreateDIBSection(memdc, (BITMAPINFO*)(&bmpInfoHdr), DIB_RGB_COLORS, 0, 0, 0);
    HGDIOBJ oldbitmap = SelectObject(memdc, hbitmap);

    //Note, GDI functions don't support alpha channel, they can't be used here
    //Use GDI+, BufferedPaint, or DrawThemeXXX functions

    BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, rc.right, caption_height, memdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    SelectObject(memdc, oldbitmap);
    DeleteObject(hbitmap);
    DeleteDC(memdc);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK wndproc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    //static MARGINS margins = { -1,-1,100,-1 };
    static MARGINS margins = { 0,0,100,0 };
    static RECT border_thickness = { 0 };

    switch(uMsg) 
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        if(GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWL_STYLE) & WS_THICKFRAME)
        {
            AdjustWindowRectEx(&border_thickness,
                GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWL_STYLE) & ~WS_CAPTION, FALSE, NULL);
            border_thickness.left *= -1;
            border_thickness.top *= -1;
        }
        else if(GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWL_STYLE) & WS_BORDER)
        {
            border_thickness = { 1,1,1,1 };
        }

        DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(hwnd, &margins);
        SetWindowPos(hwnd, NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            SWP_SHOWWINDOW | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_FRAMECHANGED);

        break;

    case WM_NCCALCSIZE:
        if(lParam)
        {
            NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS* sz = (NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS*)lParam;
            sz->rgrc[0].left += border_thickness.left;
            sz->rgrc[0].right -= border_thickness.right;
            sz->rgrc[0].bottom -= border_thickness.bottom;
            return 0;
        }
        break;

    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

        //paint caption area
        paint_caption(hwnd, hdc, margins.cyTopHeight);

        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        return 0;
    }

    case WM_NCHITTEST:
    {
        //handle close/minimize/maximize/help button
        LRESULT lResult;
        if (DwmDefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam, &lResult))
            return lResult;

        //do default processing, except change the result for caption area
        lResult = DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
        if(lResult == HTCLIENT)
        {
            POINT pt = { LOWORD(lParam), HIWORD(lParam) };
            ScreenToClient(hwnd, &pt);
            if(pt.y < border_thickness.top) return HTTOP;
            if(pt.y < margins.cyTopHeight)  return HTCAPTION;
        }

        return lResult;
    }

    case WM_NCMOUSELEAVE:
    {
        LRESULT lResult;
        if(DwmDefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam, &lResult))
            return lResult;
        break;
    }

    case WM_CLOSE:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    }

    return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Result in Windows 10:

[image]

Win 7:

[image]

Comment: The documentation for `DwmDefWindowProc()` says it also must be called for `WM_NCMOUSELEAVE`, presumably because it's that message where the glow aura on Windows 7 goes away. What makes passing 0 different from the result of passing `AdjustWindowRectEx()` on a zero rect, which will result in the needed insets? And what about Windows 10 makes it draw incorrectly? I'll boot into Windows 10 now to test the code I have to see what happens, but since I don't use it regularly I could be missing something...

Comment: I meant to write `WM_NCMOUSELEAVE`, not `WM_NCMOUSMOVE`. Corrected it. You can do the calculation for `AdjustWindowRectEx` whichever you want. You can put in zero, then `AdjustWindowRectEx` gives back small negative values, then negate those values to find the border thickness.

Comment: Ah, okay; I see what you mean by the borders needing to be set specially on Windows 10; `AdjustWindowRectEx()` is still returning Windows 7/8 values. But wait, wasn't that a compatibility setting that can be overridden with a manifest? I seem to recall that coming up in discussions here in the past. I still don't know what makes the caption buttons wrong, though. (Also FWIW everything I'm doing in the code I posted comes from the MSDN page I linked, including calling `DwmDefWindowProc()` at the top of `wndproc()`. I've expanded the above code by now. Still don't know why black brush, though.)

Comment: The code I posted works in Windows 7. Did you add `WM_PAINT` case?

Comment: In Windows 10, for resizable borders, `AdjustWindowRectEx` should return 8 pixels for all borders, with or without compatibility flags. Same as Win7/8. Maybe you are thinking of `DwmGetWindowAttribute` which gives the peculiar transparent borders in Win10 `{7,0,7,7}` (left, top, right, bottom) (but that's not relevant here). Yes, you can put `DwmDefWindowProc` on top of the code as you had done before. You don't need black brush with the above code.

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure what I'm remembering then. I wonder, if there is no way to get the actual border width in Windows 10, are the shadows included in the resizing border? That is, it still really 8 pixels, just not 8 pixels of light blue border? Either way I assume `DefWindowProc()` as you call it in your `WM_NCHITTEST` handler handles the `MARGINS==0` case correctly, right? It's a shame doing the Right Thing doesn't work anymore...

Comment: Hm, it seems the shadow being part of those 8px seems to be the case: a window with no DWM composition allows me to resize just a bit off from the edge of the window, in the shadow area, and stops right at the blue border. (I'm not sure if it's even a bit before the blue border or not; I'm also not sure if it's exactly 8 pixels of resize space.) My DWM code starts resizing and stops resizing on the blue border, shadow be damned. Interesting...

Comment: Also I still can't seem to tell a difference between the window buttons on Windows 10 on a non-DWM and a DWM window... In any case, if you're interested, here's the current version of my code, with your fixes still not applied: https://github.com/andlabs/misctestprogs/blob/master/wincompositiontest.cpp As you can see, my point is more to test the `Composited` theme subclasses, as those seem to be what controls in the extended frame use, to see what kind of UXs I can get. It's only just started, and might be split into its own repo... (You'll also notice it's not quite perfect yet; see WM_SIZE)

Comment: @BarmakShemirani You say, "It's probably easier to hide the system buttons and draw your own buttons, so the title-bar is completely custom with its own background color.". I'd like to know how to hide the system buttons eg the close button? The only way i know to do this is to turn off the style WS_SYSMENU when passing style argument to CreateWindowEx(). But doing that has the effect of completely disabling sizing in your code above.

Answer (score 1):

All right, so I investigated a bit more, trying to incorporate γηράσκω δ' αεί πολλά διδασκόμε's and Barmak Shemirani's suggestions with what I had initially (which was based on MSDN) to come up with something that seems to handle all cases in a future-proof way. Exhaustive testing shows that the below code handles Windows 10's strange border mouse-over behavior perfectly (even the top border, which even in normal windows only triggers at the blue edge, not slightly off like the others). It looks correct on Windows 10, Windows 8.1, and Windows 7. And what's more, maximizing now works properly too (or seems to work properly; I'm not sure if there's a subtle difference I'm missing or not)!

The biggest difference from Barmak's code is that I pull the `WM_NCCALCSIZE` results from `DefWindowProc()` and just filter out the top result, allowing me to take control of the top edge and let Windows decide how big the rest should be. It also means I don't need to keep track of `border_thickness` like Barmak does. Plus, it cleans up a bug I've noticed with WM_PAINT and sizing the window smaller overlapping into the borders, but I don't know why or how...

The `defWindowProcFirst` variable is what controls which behavior is used. If you set it to `FALSE`, you get the pre-Barmak behavior, which had the Windows 10 inconsistencies.

There are a few additional things to note:

- The below doesn't handle WM_PRINTCLIENT yet.
- The below doesn't return HTCLIENT for the actual client area; that shouldn't be too hard of a fix...
- The `DefWindowProcW()` return value from `WM_NCCALCSIZE` is not used, which means `rgrc[1]`, `rgrc[2]`, and `lppos` are never touched and we might be missing out on some optimizations; I'll need to figure out how to handle those
- A bunch of leftover TODOs as well

But all things considered this seems to work fine :) I should go back and test the MSDN code unmodified though; I do imagine it'll give me similar results to `defWindowProcFirst = FALSE` though...

Thanks in the meantime!

```
// 12 december 2016
#define UNICODE
#define _UNICODE
#define STRICT
#define STRICT_TYPED_ITEMIDS
// get Windows version right; right now Windows Vista
// unless otherwise stated, all values from Microsoft's sdkddkver.h
// TODO is all of this necessary? how is NTDDI_VERSION used?
// TODO plaform update sp2
#define WINVER          0x0600  /* from Microsoft's winnls.h */
#define _WIN32_WINNT        0x0600
#define _WIN32_WINDOWS  0x0600  /* from Microsoft's pdh.h */
#define _WIN32_IE           0x0700
#define NTDDI_VERSION       0x06000000
#include <windows.h>
#include <commctrl.h>
#include <uxtheme.h>
#include <windowsx.h>
#include <shobjidl.h>
#include <d2d1.h>
#include <d2d1helper.h>
#include <dwrite.h>
#include <usp10.h>
#include <msctf.h>
#include <textstor.h>
#include <olectl.h>
#include <shlwapi.h>
#include <dwmapi.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <string>

#pragma comment(linker, \
    "\"/manifestdependency:type='Win32' " \
    "name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' " \
    "version='6.0.0.0' " \
    "processorArchitecture='*' " \
    "publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' " \
    "language='*'\"")
#pragma comment(lib, "user32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "kernel32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "gdi32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "comctl32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "uxtheme.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "dwmapi.lib")

#define HR(call) printf("%s -> 0x%I32X\n", #call, call)

struct metrics {
    RECT windowRect;
    MARGINS resizeFrameInsets;
    MARGINS nonclientInsets;
    MARGINS realNonclientInsets;
    RECT effectiveClientRect;
    RECT relativeClientRect;
};

BOOL defWindowProcFirst = TRUE;

// TODO this is incorrect when maximized
void getMetrics(HWND hwnd, struct metrics *m)
{
    RECT r;

    GetWindowRect(hwnd, &(m->windowRect));

    // get the margins of the resize frame
    ZeroMemory(&r, sizeof (RECT));
    AdjustWindowRectEx(&r,
        GetWindowStyle(hwnd) & ~WS_CAPTION,
        FALSE,
        GetWindowExStyle(hwnd));
    m->resizeFrameInsets.cxLeftWidth = -r.left;
    m->resizeFrameInsets.cyTopHeight = -r.top;
    m->resizeFrameInsets.cxRightWidth = r.right;
    m->resizeFrameInsets.cyBottomHeight = r.bottom;

    // get non-client insets
    ZeroMemory(&r, sizeof (RECT));
    AdjustWindowRectEx(&r,
        GetWindowStyle(hwnd),
        FALSE,
        GetWindowExStyle(hwnd));
    m->nonclientInsets.cxLeftWidth = -r.left;
    m->nonclientInsets.cyTopHeight = -r.top;
    m->nonclientInsets.cxRightWidth = r.right;
    m->nonclientInsets.cyBottomHeight = r.bottom;
    if (defWindowProcFirst) {
        m->nonclientInsets.cxLeftWidth = 0;
        m->nonclientInsets.cxRightWidth = 0;
        m->nonclientInsets.cyBottomHeight = 0;
    }

    // give the top 2.5x the room so we can shove stuff in there
    m->realNonclientInsets = m->nonclientInsets;
    m->realNonclientInsets.cyTopHeight *= 2.5;

    // compute the effective client rect
    m->effectiveClientRect = m->windowRect;
    m->effectiveClientRect.left += m->realNonclientInsets.cxLeftWidth;
    m->effectiveClientRect.top += m->realNonclientInsets.cyTopHeight;
    m->effectiveClientRect.right -= m->realNonclientInsets.cxRightWidth;
    m->effectiveClientRect.bottom -= m->realNonclientInsets.cyBottomHeight;

    // and compute it relative to the window's real client rect
    m->relativeClientRect = m->effectiveClientRect;
    MapWindowRect(NULL, hwnd, &(m->relativeClientRect));

#if 0
// for debugging
printf("***\n");
#define PRINTRECT(r) ((int)((r).left)), ((int)((r).top)), ((int)((r).right)), ((int)((r).bottom))
printf("window rect %d %d %d %d\n", PRINTRECT(m->windowRect));
    ZeroMemory(&r, sizeof (RECT));
    AdjustWindowRectEx(&r,
        GetWindowStyle(hwnd),
        FALSE,
        GetWindowExStyle(hwnd));
r.left=-r.left;r.top=-r.top;
printf("edge insets %d %d %d %d\n", PRINTRECT(r));
HR(DwmGetWindowAttribute(hwnd, DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS, &r, sizeof (RECT)));
printf("DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS %d %d %d %d\n", PRINTRECT(r));
{HMODULE m;
m=LoadLibraryW(L"kernel32.dll");
if(m == NULL)printf("unknown os\n");
// TODO this doesn't work; apparently the function is really in one of the api-ms-core* DLLs...
else if(GetProcAddress(m,"VirtualAllocFromApp")!=NULL)printf("windows 10\n");
else if(GetProcAddress(m,"GetPackageApplicationIds")!=NULL)printf("windows 8.1\n");
else if(GetProcAddress(m,"GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime")!=NULL)printf("windows 8\n");
else printf("windows 7\n");}
printf("\n");
#endif
}

HWND rebarHost;
HWND rebar;

const char *htnames[] = {
    "HTERROR",
    "HTTRANSPARENT",
    "HTNOWHERE",
    "HTCLIENT",
    "HTCAPTION",
    "HTSYSMENU",
    "HTGROWBOX",
    "HTMENU",
    "HTHSCROLL",
    "HTVSCROLL",
    "HTMINBUTTON",
    "HTMAXBUTTON",
    "HTLEFT",
    "HTRIGHT",
    "HTTOP",
    "HTTOPLEFT",
    "HTTOPRIGHT",
    "HTBOTTOM",
    "HTBOTTOMLEFT",
    "HTBOTTOMRIGHT",
    "HTBORDER",
    "HTOBJECT",
    "HTCLOSE",
    "HTHELP",
};

LRESULT CALLBACK wndproc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    struct metrics m;
    HDC dc;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    BOOL dwmHandled;
    LRESULT lResult;

    dwmHandled = DwmDefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam, &lResult);
    getMetrics(hwnd, &m);
    switch (uMsg) {
    case WM_CREATE:
        SetWindowPos(hwnd, NULL,
            m.windowRect.left, m.windowRect.top,
            m.windowRect.right - m.windowRect.left, m.windowRect.bottom - m.windowRect.top,
            SWP_FRAMECHANGED);
        // TODO if we pass SWP_NOOWNERZORDER || SWP_NOZORDER, the default frame is not correctly inhibited

        rebarHost = CreateWindowExW(0,
            L"rebarHost", L"",
            WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_CLIPCHILDREN,
            m.realNonclientInsets.cxLeftWidth,
            m.nonclientInsets.cyTopHeight,
            m.windowRect.right - m.windowRect.left -
                m.realNonclientInsets.cxLeftWidth - m.realNonclientInsets.cxRightWidth,
            m.realNonclientInsets.cyTopHeight - m.nonclientInsets.cyTopHeight,
            hwnd, NULL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);

        rebar = CreateWindowExW(0,
            REBARCLASSNAMEW, L"",
            WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | RBS_VARHEIGHT | CCS_NODIVIDER,
            0, 0, 0, 0,
            rebarHost, NULL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);

        {
            REBARBANDINFOW rb;

            ZeroMemory(&rb, sizeof (REBARBANDINFOW));
            rb.cbSize = sizeof (REBARBANDINFOW);
            rb.fMask = RBBIM_TEXT;
            rb.lpText = L"This is a rebar";
            HR((HRESULT) SendMessageW(rebar, RB_INSERTBANDW, (WPARAM) (-1), (LPARAM) (&rb)));
        }

        SendMessageW(rebar, RB_SETWINDOWTHEME, 0,
            (LPARAM) L"NavbarComposited");

        break;
    case WM_ACTIVATE:
        HR(DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(hwnd, &(m.realNonclientInsets)));
        break;
    case WM_NCCALCSIZE:
        if (wParam != (WPARAM) FALSE) {
            NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS *op = (NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS *) lParam;
            NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS np;

            if (!defWindowProcFirst)
                return 0;
            np = *op;
            DefWindowProcW(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, (LPARAM) (&np));
            printf("old %ld %ld %ld %ld\nnew %ld %ld %ld %ld\n",
                op->rgrc[0].left, op->rgrc[0].top, op->rgrc[0].right, op->rgrc[0].bottom,
                np.rgrc[0].left, np.rgrc[0].top, np.rgrc[0].right, np.rgrc[0].bottom);
            op->rgrc[0].left = np.rgrc[0].left;
            op->rgrc[0].right = np.rgrc[0].right;
            op->rgrc[0].bottom = np.rgrc[0].bottom;
            return 0;
        }
        break;
    case WM_NCHITTEST:
        if (dwmHandled)
            return lResult;
        // DWM did not handle it; we have to do it ourselves
        if (defWindowProcFirst) {
            lResult = DefWindowProcW(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
            if (lResult != HTCLIENT) {
                printf("them %s\n", htnames[lResult + 2]);
                return lResult;
            }
        }
        {
            POINT p;

            p.x = GET_X_LPARAM(lParam);
            p.y = GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam);

            lResult = HTNOWHERE;
            if (p.y >= m.windowRect.top && p.y < (m.windowRect.top + m.resizeFrameInsets.cyTopHeight))
                lResult = HTTOP;
            else if (p.y >= m.effectiveClientRect.bottom && p.y < m.windowRect.bottom)
                lResult = HTBOTTOM;

            if (p.x >= m.windowRect.left && p.x < m.effectiveClientRect.left)
                switch (lResult) {
                case HTNOWHERE:
                    lResult = HTLEFT;
                    break;
                case HTTOP:
                    lResult = HTTOPLEFT;
                    break;
                case HTBOTTOM:
                    lResult = HTBOTTOMLEFT;
                    break;
                }
            else if (p.x >= m.effectiveClientRect.right && p.x < m.windowRect.right)
                switch (lResult) {
                case HTNOWHERE:
                    lResult = HTRIGHT;
                    break;
                case HTTOP:
                    lResult = HTTOPRIGHT;
                    break;
                case HTBOTTOM:
                    lResult = HTBOTTOMRIGHT;
                    break;
                }

            if (lResult == HTNOWHERE)
                if (p.y >= (m.windowRect.top + m.resizeFrameInsets.cyTopHeight) && p.y < m.effectiveClientRect.top)
                    lResult = HTCAPTION;

            if (defWindowProcFirst)
                printf("us %s\n", htnames[lResult + 2]);
            if (lResult != HTNOWHERE)
                return lResult;
        }
        // we can't handle it; give it to DefWindowProcW() and hope for the best
        break;
    case WM_SIZE:
        // TODO if defWindowProcFirst == FALSE, this seems to be wrong when shrinking the size on the right or bottom edges
        // TODO without this call, the WM_PAINT never fills new areas
        // we may need to handle WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED and compute new metrics from there
        // TODO what happens with defWindowProcFirst == TRUE? do we need to do anything else special? is this needed?
        InvalidateRect(hwnd, &(m.relativeClientRect), FALSE);
        break;
    case WM_PAINT:
        dc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        FillRect(dc, &(m.relativeClientRect), (HBRUSH) (COLOR_BTNFACE + 1));
        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        break;
    case WM_CLOSE:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    }
    if (dwmHandled)
        return lResult;
    return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

int main(void)
{
    INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX icc;
    WNDCLASSW wc;
    HWND mainwin;
    MSG msg;

    ZeroMemory(&icc, sizeof (INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX));
    icc.dwSize = sizeof (INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX);
    icc.dwICC = (ICC_LISTVIEW_CLASSES | ICC_TREEVIEW_CLASSES | ICC_BAR_CLASSES | ICC_TAB_CLASSES | ICC_UPDOWN_CLASS | ICC_PROGRESS_CLASS | ICC_HOTKEY_CLASS | ICC_ANIMATE_CLASS | ICC_WIN95_CLASSES | ICC_DATE_CLASSES | ICC_USEREX_CLASSES | ICC_COOL_CLASSES | ICC_INTERNET_CLASSES | ICC_PAGESCROLLER_CLASS | ICC_NATIVEFNTCTL_CLASS | ICC_STANDARD_CLASSES | ICC_LINK_CLASS);
    InitCommonControlsEx(&icc);

    ZeroMemory(&wc, sizeof (WNDCLASSW));
    wc.lpszClassName = L"mainwin";
    wc.lpfnWndProc = wndproc;
    wc.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    wc.hIcon = LoadIconW(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursorW(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) GetStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH);
    RegisterClassW(&wc);

    ZeroMemory(&wc, sizeof (WNDCLASSW));
    wc.lpszClassName = L"rebarHost";
    wc.lpfnWndProc = DefWindowProcW;
    wc.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    wc.hIcon = LoadIconW(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursorW(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) GetStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH);
    RegisterClassW(&wc);

    mainwin = CreateWindowExW(0,
        L"mainwin", L"Main Window",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        400, 400,
        NULL, NULL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);

    ShowWindow(mainwin, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
    UpdateWindow(mainwin);

    while (GetMessageW(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessageW(&msg);
    }
    return 0;
}
```